# Implement svg icons into web

Tags: html, css, svg, fonts, icons

I'm looking for best solution how to implement .svg icons into web.

Basically, I need to implement just few icons, what I have in my .psd, so I can choose any format, but it will be nice to have vector so I've choosed .svg.

Only, the problem is that I need to change color of that picture and also I need to be sure that it will be supported on all major browsers, IE as well.

For now, I'm using tag < object > which works nicely, but I'm unsure about browser support and also I can't simply change color.

How would you solve this situation ?

The .svg icons are very small and simple, I've also thought to convert them into fonts or icons, but not sure about best workflow how to do it properly.

Also, I was thinking about using .pngs, but there is a problem with changing colors and of course "scaleabness", but if I will not find out anything, I will probably end up with this...

I personaly like working with fonts (like font awesome and so...), as they are scaleable, colorable.... and displayed everywhere

Is possible to convert and add these icons from .psd to such a format, that will be close to fonts ?

Thank you for your answers :)

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score 1):

Check browser support for the  various ways to implement SVG at http://caniuse.com/

Common workflows:

- Automatically process .svg files into icon fonts, usable in CSS, with `Gulp`
- Automatically insert .SVG content into HTML as data URIs, with server middleware
- Insert all SVG icons inline into a page and reference as SVG Symbols
- Insert all icons into one SVG document as individual symbols, and refer to individually with svg 'use' - https://css-tricks.com/svg-use-with-external-reference-take-2/

Answer (score 0):

So I've found a solution

I've generated my own fonts from .svg. As icons we're small, there we're no problem to work with them like fonts. 
I've used

http://fontastic.me/

Very easy to work with, just upload your .svg, make some customisations like name of your fonts, mapping and add them into your page.